# Concurrency. Checking if a few objects are taken at the same time?

Tags: java, concurrency

In class `X`, I have multiple objects of class `Manufacture` that are started like this

```
for(int k=0; k < manNum; k++){
        Queue1 = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Rekord>(data.addQueue());
        Queue2 = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Rekord>(data.minQueue());
        Queue3 = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Rekord>(data.multiQueue());

        ManufacturePattern manPat=new ManufacturePattern(Queue1, Queue2, Queue3, k);
    }
```

Inside ManufacturePattern there are `AdditionMachines`, `MultiplyingMachines` and `Workers`. `Workers` are started with

```
        service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numWorkers);
        for (int i=0; i < numWorkers; i++) {
            service.submit(new Producer(Queue1, Queue2, Queue3, addMachines, multiMachines, waitingMultiMachines,i));
        }
```

So each worker draw itself an equation. And if it's addition he is supposed to take `AdditonMachine` to do the job for him. If it's subtraction, he can count everything by himself. If it is multiplying, he has to wait till other worker will come and help him. Before drawing, worker checks if any employee with multiplying machine is waiting for colleague. If not, then he can draw. All the queues in the program are blockingQueues (Queue1, Queue2, Queue3, addMachines, multiMachines, waitingMultiMachines).

```
if(waitingMachine.isEmpty()){
 // he can draw an equation and if necessary take proper machine
}
else{
MultiplyingMachine multi = waitingMachine.take(); 
// count stuff;
// make Your friend leave the machine, put it back on queue
}
```

The problem is with machines. For some reason workers seem not to notice that there is machine in waiting queue or a few workers try to take same machines at the same time. What would be a solution to that problem?

Comment: Your last paragraph regarding drawing equations is unclear. Why does it have to wait? Elaborate more

Comment: Our teacher imaged a situation where for multiplying equation two workers are needed. So there I am, following the requirements

Comment: Be very careful about using operations like `isEmpty` or `size` on a concurrent queue as the state of the queue may change and invalidate your guard immediately following the guard statement - when possible, stick to `poll/take` or `offer/put`. Also, is it possible that a machine might be in multiple queues at the same time?  This would explain how multiple workers are getting the same machine despite your using thread-safe queues.